Python でループする関数を有する場合のasyncioの使い方
asyncioを用いて、loop関数の10秒待機の後、printhello関数の60秒を待たずに"done"をプリント、while Trueでloop関数に戻り、繰り返す
つまり、loop関数が終わった60秒後に毎回"hello"をプリントする方法を知りたいです。
ここでは分かりやすいようにloop関数をfor文を使ってループさせていますが、実際のコードはwhile Trueで条件が揃ったらbreakしmain関数を開始するようにしています。
import time

def loop():
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        x = i + 1
        print(x)
        
        if x == 10:
            break
               
def printhello():
    time.sleep(60)
    print("hello")
       
def main():
    while True:
        loop()
        printhello()   
        print("done")
        
main()


どこまで調べたのでしょう？ どこまで進んでいますか？
また, 疑問に思っている箇所はどこでしょう。ヘルプセンターの 質問にあたって にガイドがあるので参考に

こんな記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。コルーチンと Task, python asyncio fails to concurrently run two infinite functions, How to execute 2 coroutines in Python 3.6, What are Coroutines in Python and How to Create it, Coroutine in Python

希望している動作の細かい内容がイマイチ読み取りづらいのですが、以下のようなことだと想定します。

main()のwhile True:ループの中で以下の順番で処理が行われる

loop()の処理が単独で行われる。この部分が実行されている間は何も他の処理は動かない。while True:ループが繰り返し実行されている場合でも同じ。
loop()の処理が終了した後に、printhello()とprint('done')の処理が非同期並行して行われる。人間の目には先ずdoneが表示されて、約60秒後にhelloが表示されるように見える。
printhello()とprint('done')の両方が完了したらwhile True:ループの1回分が終了し、次の回のループ処理が始まる。



ということで、コルーチンと Task の中から コルーチン, Awaitable, スリープ, 並行な Task 実行 あたり、それから 非同期プログラムの実行 を参照して対処すれば良いでしょう。

main()や非同期並行処理を行う関数にはasyncを付ける。
main()の実行には asyncio.run()を使う。
非同期並行処理中のsleep()はtime.sleep()ではなくawait asyncio.sleep()を使う。
非同期並行処理を呼び出すにはawait asyncio.gather()を使う。
非同期並行処理として同期処理(質問ではprint('done'))をそのまま指定することは出来ないので、間接的にprint()を呼び出すasyncな関数(async def printasync())を作っておき、asyncio.gather()でそれを指定する。

上記を適用すると質問のソースコードは以下のようになるでしょう。
行末に ####を付けた部分が変更点です。
import asyncio ####
import time

def loop():
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        x = i + 1
        print(x)
        
        if x == 10:
            break

async def printhello(): ####
    await asyncio.sleep(60) ####
    print("hello")

async def printasync(s): ####
    print(s) ####

async def main(): ####
    while True:
        loop()
        await asyncio.gather( ####
            printhello(),
            printasync('done') ####
        )

asyncio.run(main()) ####


なお、質問の最後の実際のコードはwhile Trueで条件が揃ったらbreakしmain関数を開始するようにしています。については、どういうことなのか分からなかったので考慮していません。
